# Project file cannot specify more than one Splash Screen element

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I can't believe this. I tried to add splash screen by following the guidelines from the MSDN but my WPF application project broke because of this. Now I cannot debug & run the application anymore.

The only message that I get is:

`Project file cannot specify more than one Splash Screen element`

There is no location where it happens. When I take a look at the output window, it looks like this..

`------ Build started: Project: MPCS Line Off, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(269,9): error MC1004: Project file cannot specify more than one SplashScreen element.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(269,9): error BG1003: The project file contains a property value that is not valid.`

I have searched high and low, but no luck. FYI this is in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one file with "Build Action = SplashScreen"

Comment: And how can I find those file? As long as I remember, I only set one splash screen

Comment: Sorry for the *REALLY* long delay, unload the project from the solution explorer (right click -> unload) and open it for edit (right click -> edit) You should find more than one of those items